# Is it possible to display a treeview with node image based on the underlying class of the node?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I have a hierarchical collection that is meant to represent a directory structure where any directory can contain directories and bookmarks and any bookmark cannot contain anything. Both of the classes extend a base abstract class.

I'm running into issues when I try to handle the image associated with a node based on what its class is. Based on what I've Googled, I understand that `HierarchicalDataTemplate` is the way to go, but I seem to be missing something in my implementation. With the code below, no tree is displayed, even though Bookmarks does contain values.

Below is the XAML I'm working with:

```
<TreeView
    ItemsSource="{Binding Bookmarks}">
    <TreeView.Resources>

        <!-- Directories -->
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate
            DataType="{x:Type BaseBookmarks:BookmarkDirectory}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
            <TreeViewItem
                Header="{Binding SimpleName}">
                <Image
                    Source="/MapInterface;component/icons/16x16_BookmarkFolder.png" />
            </TreeViewItem>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <!-- Bookmarks -->
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate
            DataType="{x:Type BaseBookmarks:Bookmark}">
            <TreeViewItem
                Header="{Binding SimpleName}">
                <Image
                    Source="/MapInterface;component/icons/16x16_Bookmark.png" />
            </TreeViewItem>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use a TreeViewItem in the DataTemplate. The TreeView will take care of creating the TreeViewItems and setting their content property with your template.
This should work:

```
 <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Bookmarks}">
        <TreeView.Resources>

            <!-- Directories -->
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type BaseBookmarks:BookmarkDirectory}"
                                       ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="/MapInterface;component/icons/16x16_BookmarkFolder.png"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SimpleName}"/>       
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

            <!-- Bookmarks -->
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type BaseBookmarks:Bookmark}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="/MapInterface;component/icons/16x16_Bookmark.png" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SimpleName}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```